# Move checkboxlist from one groupbox to another groupbox for windows form using c#

Tags: c#

This form is created using windows application under menu1 have submenus also on click of submenu i have to display checkboxlist in groupbox on click of checkbox and click of move button the list of command should be displayed on the other groupbox and i have to buttons "delete" and "clear"
on click of delete button the selected command should be deleted from the list and the click of clear button the list command displayed should be cleared from the groupbox and i also want to display the number selected checkboxlist in the message box for windows form using c#

can any1 help me on this.. please provide me the code aslo....

```
        With Regards,
         Sweety
```

Answer (score 3):

let's say you have [chkList1 : your first CheckListBox] ,
[lstBox1 : your destination]
btnAdd,  btnDel,  btnClear

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in chkList1.SelectedItems)
        {
            if (!lstBox1.Items.Contains(item))
                lstBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in lstBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            lstBox1.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstBox1.Items.Clear();
        //if you want to hide the lstBox you'll write
        //lstBox1.Visible = true;
    }
```